# PCA, dot product, column space

Tags: pca, linear

Let's assume a data matrix $X_{n\times p}$. The idea of PCA is to find the projection $Xv$ that has the maximum variance. When thinking about column space $C(X)$ then $Xv$ is obviously a linear combination of columns of $X$, so we seek for that particular vector $c^* \in C(X)$ that maximizes the projection variance. Now let's think about $X$ as of $n$ $p-$dimensional points. $Xv$ can be seen as a dot product between each $p-$dimensional point (vector; denoted as $x_i$) and the vector $v$, so in the resulting vector (say, $c = Xv$) each entry $c_i$ is a length of projection of $x_i$ onto $v$, multiplied by the length of $v$ (that is equal $1$ when $v$ is an eigenvector). If this is true, then obviously we get most information when we maximize variance of that vector (projection). Am I correct?

Comment: (1) What do you mean by "most information"?  (2) Assuming this is intended as another way of saying "most variance," then your question looks circular: isn't it answered in the second sentence, "The idea ... maximum variance"?

Comment: @whuber "most information" was my clumsy synonym "most variance". Now as I read my question it seems awkward indeed, but the point is: is my reasoning regarding dot product correct?

Comment: I don't see that these statements about dot products actually say anything useful about PCA.  They seem to recapitulate basic properties of dot products.

Comment: @whuber I am sorry, let me try again. I want to understand PCA visually but in terms of row space, e.g. $p=2$, the simple scatterplot. So if the whole idea of PCA revolves around maximizing the variance of the data projection $Xv$ my question is whether thinking of $Xv$ as of the dot product between $x_i$ and $v$ (that by definition gives for each $x_i$ the projection length onto unit vector $v$) is valid.

Comment: Why not just transpose $X$ then?  The rows become columns and you're good to go.